# Cannot open file using .getResource(fullPath)

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea

I am trying to open a file on a Mac. The file is located outside the package with the main file. I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "WAV files", "wav");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(yourJFrame);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
                    chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
        }

        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

       >> AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(Main.class.getResource(fullPath));
        clip.play();
```

Error is marked with `>>`

Comment: The argument to Class.getResource is not a filename.  It’s a relative URL, whose base is the root of each entry in the classpath.  getResource can *never* retrieve a file outside of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this instead:

```
URL url = file.toURI().toURL()
AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip( url );
```

Class.getResource is a bit problematic, it assumes by default paths are relative, and is somewhat dependant on the classloader being used.

Also are you sure the file is chosen, your if statement only wraps the println and not the rest of the functionality, which means if a file was not chosen a null pointer may also occur. Albeit the NPE would happen on the line above.

Also as a side note I would avoid using AWT as it was superseded by swing, which itself was superseded by javafx.

Comment: I don’t see AWT being used here.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to Class.getResource is not a filename. It’s a relative URL, whose base is the root of each entry in the classpath. getResource can *never* retrieve a file outside of the classpath.  Since your filename is not a valid URL relative to the classpath root, the getResource method returns null (as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))).

You could do as Jack Moxley suggested, and properly convert the file to a URL.

However, [the Applet class is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/applet/Applet.html). You should play sounds using the [javax.sound.sampled package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html):

```
try {
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
    clip.start();
} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```